# Spring GAE/J Could Not find API version error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I am trying to use Spring MVC 3 on GAE/J and I got this error and I do not know what it means, does anybody have an idea and perhaps give me pointers on how to fix this?

```
May 21, 2010 9:50:23 AM com.google.appengine.tools.info.LocalVersionFactory getVersion
INFO: Could not find API version from /opt/home/me/workspace/SpringMVC/war/WEB-INF/lib/.svn
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:133)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.ApiVersionFinder.findApiVersion(ApiVersionFinder.java:37)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.LocalVersionFactory.getVersion(LocalVersionFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.getLocalVersion(UpdateCheck.java:112)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.checkForUpdates(UpdateCheck.java:91)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.doNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:164)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.UpdateCheck.maybePrintNagScreen(UpdateCheck.java:132)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:150)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
```

Comment: This seems to be a common bug, I've experienced it too. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3051

Comment: Interesting, I am using Spring 3/GAE/J and I've never experienced this issue. However, I'm using Maven and it looks like folks having this issue are not based on the Google Code issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just a wild guess: It looks like you have packaged the hidden subversion directory (.svn) in your war file. Usually these directories are not deployed. Maybe removing it from the war file  ?